# Open Outlook and display email item with attachment by MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Please suggest how to open outlook and display email with attachment in MVC4.
I tried with both client side & Server side, after IIS deployment for certain users(with no admin rights),it is not working.
Please find the below code which I used to create email:

Server Side:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        oMailItem.Attachments.Add(pathWithFilename);
        oMailItem.Display(true);
```

Client Side By jQuery:

```
 var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
                var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
                mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
                theMailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.NotemA');

                theMailItem.Attachments.add(result);
                theMailItem.display(0);
```

Thanks,
Sathesh

Comment: Have you checked the security settings for those users? I'm not sure what the specific settings are but perhaps those users can't run the ActiveX content because of Trust settings.